# Wait until scrollbar fades when using UI Automator

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I'm using UI Automator for automating screenshots of my app. But I want to ensure the scrollbar has faded out before taking the screenshot. Currently I'm simply using the naïve approach of calling `SystemClock.sleep()` but I'm wondering if there's a way to detect the presence of a scrollbar either as a separate object or as a property of a ListView and wait for a state change?

As an alternative solution, is it possible to disable scrollbars during tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UiDevice.waitForWindowUpdate(PackageName, timeout).

I'm not sure if it works for fading scrollbars but I think it should. It basically waits for the window to be updated or until a defined timeout.

EDIT: Another way: if you have the corresponding UiObject you can use [waitUntilGone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html#waitUntilGone(long))

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The scrollbars are still visible on my screenshots. I tried calling waitForWindowUpdate both with null and my package name as argument. Re the waitUntilGone approach, I can't see a way to get the scrollbars as a UiObject. I don't know if they are separate objects.